# Scala for comprehensions and partial map

Tags: scala, for-comprehension

The Scala language specification section **6.19** says:

> A for comprehension `for (p <- e) yield e0` is translated to `e.map { case p => e0 }`

So...

```
scala> val l : List[Either[String, Int]] = List(Left("Bad"), Right(1))
l: List[Either[String,Int]] = List(Left(Bad), Right(1))

scala> for (Left(x) <- l) yield x
res5: List[String] = List(Bad)
```

So far so good:

```
scala> l.map { case Left(x) => x }
<console>:13: warning: match is not exhaustive!
missing combination          Right

       l.map { case Left(x) => x }
             ^
scala.MatchError: Right(1)
    at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:13)
    at ...
```

Why does the second version not work? Or rather, *why does the first version work?*

Comment: using l.collect{ case Left(x) => x } instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use pattern matching in your `for`-comprehension the compiler will actually insert a call to `filter` with an `instanceOf`-check before applying the `map`.

**EDIT:**

Also in section 6.19 it says:

> A generator p <- e followed by a guard if g is translated to a single generator p <- e.withFilter((x1, ..., xn) => g ) where x1, ..., xn are the free variables of p.

A generator is defined earlier on as:

> Generator ::= Pattern1 ‘<-’ Expr [Guard]

When inspecting the bytecode you will see the call to `filter` preceding the call to `map`.

Comment: Can you point to the bit of the specification that talk about this? I thought that `filter` only applied to **guards**: i.e. `for (e <- if cond)`

Comment: 6.19 For Comprehensions and For Loops
The translation scheme is as follows. In a first step, every generator p <e,
where
p is not irrefutable (§8.1) for the type of e is replaced by
p <e.
withFilter { case p => true; case _ => false }
Then, the following rules are applied repeatedly until all comprehensions have been
eliminated.
• A for comprehension for (p <e
) yield e0 is translated to
e.map { case p => e0 }.

Answer (score 2):

As an addition to Eastsun's remarks: Scala 2.8 has a method collect, which would work in your example:

```
l.collect { case Left(x) => x }
//--> List[String] = List(Bad)
```

Comment: i resorted to for-comprehending in step 1 and then a separate collect on the result of the for-comprehension in step 2. is there any way to "collect" in a for comprehension to prevent having to have two "steps"?

Answer (score 1):

Scala 2.7 language specification, page 83, second paragraph from the bottom (don't have the 2.8 spec here).  Inserting filters for generator pattern-matching is the first step in the for-comprehension translation process.

One caveat, the last time I checked, this doesn't work for typed patterns, which can be surprising.  So in your example

```
for(x:Left <- l) yield x
```

wouldn't work, throwing a type error

Comment: It can by tricked: val as = Seq("a", 1, true, ()); for (a @ (dummy: Boolean) <- as) yield a